# Implementation of a Doubly Linked List

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, iterator

I am trying to implement a linked list, and I am completely lost. I'm getting break points all over the place, specifically with the erase method. Whenever I alter the erase method, some error will inevitably spring up. I've got pointer errors, problems with the destructor that only occur when the erase method is called, and so on.

Here's what I have so far:

Header file:

```
#pragma once

class IntList {
private:

    class IntNode {
    public:
        IntNode(int v, IntNode *pr, IntNode *nx);
        ~IntNode();
        IntNode* previous;
        IntNode* next;

        class iterator {

        public:
            iterator(IntNode* t);
            int& operator*();
            iterator& operator++();
            iterator& operator--();
            bool operator!=(iterator other)const;
        private:
            IntNode* target;
        };

    private:
        int value;
    };

    IntNode* head;
    IntNode* tail;
    int count;

public:

    IntList();
    ~IntList();
    void push_back(int v);
    void pop_back();
    int size() const { return count; }
    typedef IntNode::iterator iterator;
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
    //unsigned int size() const;
    void push_front(int value);
    bool empty() const;
    int& front();
    int& back();
    void clear();
    iterator erase(iterator position);
};
```

Implementation:

```
#include "IntList.h"
#include <stdexcept>

IntList::IntList() : head{ nullptr }, tail{ nullptr }, count{ 0 }
{}

IntList::~IntList() {
    while (head) {
        head = head->next;
        delete head;
    }
}

void IntList::push_back(int v) {
    tail = new IntNode{ v, tail, nullptr };
    if (!head) { head = tail; }
    count += 1;
}

void IntList::pop_back() {
    tail = tail->previous;
    delete tail->next;
    count -= 1;
}

IntList::iterator IntList::begin()
{
    return iterator{ head };
}

IntList::iterator IntList::end() {
    return iterator{ nullptr };
}

void IntList::push_front(int value) {
    head = new IntNode{ value, nullptr, head };
    if (!tail) { tail = head; }
    count += 1;
}

bool IntList::empty() const{
    return (count==0);
}

int& IntList::front() {
    return *begin();
}

int& IntList::back() {
    return *begin();
}

void IntList::clear() {
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    count = 0;
}

IntList::iterator IntList::erase(iterator position) {

    int midpointL = 0;

    for (iterator index = begin(); index != position; ++index) {
        midpointL++;
    }

    if (midpointL == 0) {
        head = head->next;
    }
    else if (midpointL == count) {
        tail = tail->previous;
    }
    else {

        // Move head to get a reference to the component that needs to be deleted
        for (int i = 0; i < midpointL; i++) {
            head = head->next;
        }

        // Change the previous and next pointers to point to each other
        (head->previous)->next = (head->next);
        (head->next)->previous = (head->previous);

        for (int i = midpointL-1; i > 0; i++) {
            head = head->previous;
        }

    }

    count-=1;

    return position;
}


IntList::IntNode::IntNode(int v, IntNode * pr, IntNode * nx)
    : previous{ pr }, next{ nx }, value{ v }
{
    if (previous) { previous->next = this; }
    if (next) { next->previous = this; }
}

IntList::IntNode::~IntNode() {
    if (previous) previous->next = next;
    if (next) next->previous = previous;
}

IntList::IntNode::iterator::iterator(IntNode* t)
    : target{ t }
{}

int& IntList::IntNode::iterator::operator*() {
    if (!target) { throw std::runtime_error{ "Deferenced sentinel iterator." }; }
    return target->value;
}

IntList::IntNode::iterator& IntList::IntNode::iterator::operator++()
{
    if (target) { target = target->next; }
    return *this;
}

IntList::IntNode::iterator& IntList::IntNode::iterator::operator--()
{
    if (target) { target = target->previous; }
    return *this;
}

bool IntList::IntNode::iterator::operator!=(iterator other)const
{
    return (!(target == other.target));
}
```

Could anyone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) already exists. 2) you probably *really* just want to use a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead (in real life, a linked list is a *horrible* data structure with abysmal performance).

Comment: I think he is doing this for practice, also Linked Lists have their own usage such as when you need constant-time insertions/deletions from the list (such as in real-time computing where time predictability is absolutely critical)

Comment: "int& IntList::back() {
    return *begin();
}" - that just looks *wrong*. Why yould `end()` return `begin()`? That just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @BlooB the research aspect is valid (but OP *could* have mentioned that he was doing it for learning purposes). The Big O argument doesn't really hold in real life - modern CPUs *really* don't like chasing pointers all over memory (which is what you'll be doing while looking for your insertion point) - a vector is much, much friendlier to the prefetcher. Sure, in *theory* lists have faster insertion, but in *practice*; vector beats them every time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I do Understand that Big O does not hold in real life. 

Where they excel is that we can split a list into two lists, for example, by simply storing a new pointer and manipulating a pointer or two. We can move nodes from one list to another in constant time by mere pointer manipulation, and an empty list can simply have the memory cost of a single head pointer. This stands when Linked List is backed backed by a fixed allocator.

Comment: I share @JesperJuhl 's assessment, but on a low end micro controller, without all the bells and whistles of a modern processor, a linked list ain't that bad, and a `vector` can be a memory fragmentation fatality waiting to happen. Mind you, in this world you pre-allocate all of the list nodes  and when you run out... Well, what you do depends on what you happen to need the node for.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a kind of quick review here:

```
IntList::~IntList() {
    while (head) {
        head = head->next;
        delete head;
    }
}
```

you should do instead:

```
IntList::~IntList() {
    while (head) {
        IntNode* newHead = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = newHead;
    }
}
```

as you are deleting the "next" object and then you are trying to get access to it in the next iteration.

```
void IntList::pop_back() {
    tail = tail->previous;
    delete tail->next;
    count -= 1;
}
```

Here you are not checking if tail is null or if it is pointing to head..(what's the empty condition?), maybe `count!=0`? in case you may delete a not existing next-node

```
IntList::iterator IntList::end() {
    return iterator{ nullptr };
}
```

..`end` is null? ebd should be your tail...

```
int& IntList::back() {
    return *begin();
}
```

that's begin..not back.

```
void IntList::clear() {
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    count = 0;
}
```

a clear should release all the objects in the list. You are generating garbage here (leaks).

I stopped here, sorry for that, it's just a coffee break. But you should look carefully at:
* null pointer usage
* delete your node list item when not needed
* pay attention to do not use invalid pointers (like `head->previous->next` I saw somewhere)

You have to review your code, bottom up. Hope that those first hints help you through your learning process.

Have fun,
Ste